# RegExp selecting strings surrounded by brackets

Tags: c#, regex

My purpouse is to select every character which is surrounded by `{` and `}`, this is easily achievable using this regexp `{\w*}`.

I've developed an extenstion method for strings:

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> ObtainTokens(this string originalString)
    {
        Regex expression = new Regex(@"{\w*}");
        foreach (Match element in expression.Matches(originalString))
        {
            //Exclude the brackets from the returned valued
            yield return Regex.Replace(element.Value, @"{*}*", "");
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to get rid of of `Regex.Replace`?
Returning the values as IEnumerable is a good choice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify your regexp: `{(\w*)}` and then replace:

```
yield return Regex.Replace(element.Value, @"{*}*", "");
```

with

```
yield return element.Groups[1].Value;
```

ps: full code is avaialbe [here](https://gist.github.com/4275479)

Comment: By applying your suggestion on the test string `{THIS} is a {TEST}` the response is an `IEnumerable<string>` containing two empty string.

Comment: regex has beed updated to capture groups: `{(\w*)}`